# How to add new contenteditable div after first contenteditable div exceed the height using jquery ajax in php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one contenteditable div in my webpage but now what I need is, when the max-height of the div will be exceeded then same new div will be automatically created.

Also the div look like previous one. Not only one div will appear it'ld be 10 to 15 div. One more thing when I remove the all content of second div, it will hide. 
Please anyone one help me. From last 15 days I am trying to make this.

Comment: Can you add some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: please image o code (html,css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $('div.contenteditable').on('keypress',function(e){
        if(this.offsetHeight>=parseInt($(this).css('max-height'),10)) {
            if(!$(this).next('.contenteditable').length){
                $clone=$(this).clone();
                $clone.html('');
                $clone.insertAfter($(this));
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/tkAQ8/)**

**Updated** if you want to bind all `contenteditable divs` then try this,

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('keypress','div.contenteditable',function(e){
        // check the offset height with max-height
        if(this.offsetHeight>=parseInt($(this).css('max-height'),10)) {
            // check editable div is inserted after it or not
            if(!$(this).next('.contenteditable').length){
                $clone=$(this).clone();// making clone
                $clone.html('');// empty it
                $clone.insertAfter($(this));// inserting after current div
            } else { // if already exists
                $(this).next('.contenteditable').focus();// focus it
                return false; // and return false for the current
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/tkAQ8/1/)**

To remove the `editable divs` add this in your code,

```
var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
if (code == 8 || code == 46) {
   if($('div.contenteditable').length >1 && // check length of editable divs
              // replace br's created by break-word property
              $(this).html().replace(/<br*>/,'')=='') { 
     $(this).remove();
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

**[Remove div demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/tkAQ8/2/)**

Comment: Thank you very much. i cannot explain how much i'm happy now. new div created. but here another some problem when i remove the content of new coming div at that time div not hide or remove. please give some suggestion, also i want to use padding for the div. please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Check my updated code and last [remove div demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/tkAQ8/2/)

Comment: the remove option is not working perfectly. when i delete the content the div didn't remove. please tell me the way.

Comment: If you empty the div it will remove it

Comment: Thank you so much. now this working fine. But another problem when i add the padding 1 in for all side it only wrote 1 character then automatically add new div. Could you help me please about it?

Comment: One more thing the first div also remove. i don't want this. so what can i do now?

Comment: First div is not removing check the last demo once again or see [demo-with-padding](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/tkAQ8/3/). Also you should try yourself, change the `height` with `padding`, according to your specification.

Comment: yes i changed the height with my specification. it works fine padding 20px but if i use 650px height and 80px padding here i saw the problem . anyway would u pls test it in chrome browser? maybe their have some problem to remove created div.

Comment: i faced another problem, when i wrote  at that time it works fine. but if i paste something here the new div not create automatically.please give me some solution.

Comment: You have to check conditions **[onpaste()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onpaste)**